# How to find specific item in mongodb database or all items?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I'm trying to find a specific item like this :

```
Product.find({ category: "bracelet" });
```

But in one case I need to put either a value like bracelet in category or basically say category of any like this :

```
  let cat;
  if (req.body.cat) {
    cat = req.body.cat;
  } else {
    cat = "";
  }

  let products;
  try {
    products = await Product.find({ category: cat });
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
```

So I put an empty string to find all items no matter what category field value they have but it doesn't work and returns an empty array .

How can I achieve this kind of behavior which says if there is a cat field on the request body search for that otherwise search for all items no matter of what category field value they have ?

Comment: When cat is set to "", only those items will be returned in which the category property is "". So if there are no items  with category "", you will get an empty array. Empty string does not mean that it will return all the docs. If you want to get all docs just do `Product.find({})` in `if/else` where you set cat to "".

Comment: using "await" without "async"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with a trick by saying find all that have category field or category field exist :

```
  let cat;
  if (req.body.cat) {
    cat = req.body.cat;
  } else {
    cat = { $exists: true };
  }
```

This way It will either search for the category from the request body if included and if not it will get all the items with category field .

Answer (score 1):

```
let cat;
if (req.body.cat) {
 cat = req.body.cat;
} else {
  cat = {$regex:".*."};
}

let products;
try {
 products = await Product.find({ category: cat });
} catch (e) {
 return next(e);
}
```